# Pull to refresh not stopping

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7, pull-to-refresh

Framework7 Pull to refresh Not stopping

Already Tried These Methods are Not Working:app.ptr.done() , app.ptr.destroy(), app.pullToRefreshDone();

```
 var $ptrContent = $$('.ptr-content');
        $ptrContent.on('ptr:refresh', function (e) {

          setTimeout(function () {

            app.ptr.done(); // app.ptr.destroy() // app.pullToRefreshDone()

          }, 1500);
    });

<div class="page-content ptr-content">
<div class="ptr-preloader">
<div class="preloader"></div>
<div class="ptr-arrow"></div>
</div>

<div>

var $ptrContent = $$('.ptr-content');
$ptrContent.on('ptr:refresh', function (e) {

setTimeout(function () {

app.ptr.done();

}, 1500);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

var $ptrContent = $$('.ptr-content');
$ptrContent.on('ptr:refresh', function (e) {

setTimeout(function () {

e.done();

}, 1500);
 });